# Error in executing commands in GRASS GIS

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, data

I'm using Grass 6.4.3RC2. I have a problem because when I execute the command:

```
r.radcov csv_file=cell_list_hataDEM_umts_amc_testTEST.csv dem_map-AlbSRTMdem@PERMANENT clutter_map=AlbClut@PERMANENT out_map=dita_hataDEM_umts_amc_TEST frequency=2500 --o
```

It an error appears:

> READING AND CHECIKNG THE RADIO SECTOR CSV TABLE...
>
> ERROR: Cannot open Radio cell/sector input file

I added the file "antennamap" and file "cell_list_hataDEM_umts_amc_testTEST, I have done as is described in GRASS-RaPlaT Radio Planning Tool for GRASS, User Manual, page 4 and page 8.

I'm looking forward of any solution.

Comment: You need to have the file "cell_list_hataDEM_umts_amc_testTEST.csv" in the current directory or specify the path to it.

Comment: First of all thnx for your reply. But I wanted to know how can I specify the path in which this file it is. I mean this file "cell_list_hataDEM_umts_amc_testTEST.csv" is in that path "Home_RaPlaT" ... so can you tell me please how can I execute this command specifying the path.                I'm looking forward to your reply                               Thanks

Comment: It should be: r.radcov csv_file=/path/to/file.csv ...

Answer (score 1):

Well this is confusing. Try to use short names because sometimes long names might cause you problems. eg. "dem_map-AlbSRTMdem" don't use "-" in names. Try "_" and make names shorter. Perhaps that is your problem (according to what I see).

Comment: I tried to make names shorter as you said but nothing.... same thing, same error :(